# Convert foreign versions of ascii characters

Tags: c#, encoding, ascii

I have some characters like:
ＴＤ

Which is obviously different from "TD". How can I convert ＴＤ to TD (or similar characters) in C#?

It seems that the ＴＤ happens when you try to input normal characters with a japanese (or other language) keyboard.

Edit: Duplicate has the same problem, but is not C#. See my answer for a C# duplicate that solved my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to transform japanese english character to normal english character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776998/how-to-transform-japanese-english-character-to-normal-english-character)

Comment: You can detect the input character set (i.e., Japanese character sets, Korean character sets, etc.) through the `GetCharsInRange` as explained in this [StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15806958/5209610). Do you think that the ASCII output of Japanese characters (i.e., UTF-8 encoding) is really meaningful? What information would "TD" give you? The problem is slightly easier if you're working with Latin scripts with accents - in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13769669/5209610) you'll see how you replace accented character with their "un-accented" versions.

Comment: From the title and a glance, it is indeed a duplicate.
@VladislavMartin I need to compare if the found string is == "TD". But some parts of what i read are ＴＤ and some are TD. That's why I need the conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the duplicate question was indeed my problem, what solved my problem was another answer to a different duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25149897/2026623

Using the String.Normalize method, I was able to convert the characters to their half-width counterparts.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the difference between ＴＤ and TD is not at all obvious in some browsers (or is it other OS's?). All I know is that I couldn't tell a difference between the characters in this question while viewing it on a Ubuntu machine in Firefox, but I CAN tell the difference very clearly now that I am looking at it on a Windows machine in Chrome. Now the character formatting problem is way more obvious to me :)

Comment: I tested on some different browsers (windows only) but even though the appearances of the full-width characters are different in each browser, you can still see the difference compared to the half-width versions.
So it should be an OS-thing.